# What is Ember data's defaultTransaction?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What exactly is the `'defaultTransaction'` in `get(this, 'defaultTransaction').commit();` of [ember-data's store](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L940)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the source code [inline documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L923):

> This method delegates saving to the store's implicit
>       transaction. Calling this method is essentially a request to persist
>       any changes to records that were not explicitly added to
>       a transaction.

Since you can create a new transaction to control how your records are persisted, imagine you don't - this is the case where the `defaultTransaction` comes in. In other words, a transaction is needed every-time you do some CRUD with your records, but if you don't specify one then the store's `defaultTransaction` is used.

To make even more clear, see the method `createRecord` taken from [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L272):

```
createRecord: function(type, properties, transaction) {
  properties = properties || {};

  // Create a new instance of the model `type` and put it
  // into the specified `transaction`. If no transaction is
  // specified, the default transaction will be used.
  var record = type._create({
    store: this
  });

  transaction = transaction || get(this, 'defaultTransaction');
  ...
```

The code line `transaction = transaction || get(this, 'defaultTransaction');` reveals it all, as you can see, if no transaction is specified for the record just created the `defaultTransaction` will be used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still unclear. What exactly is `'defaultTransaction'`? A variable? A function? A class-like JS thing?Where is it first defined or initiated?

Comment: @HaoQiLi it's an instance of a `DS.Transaction` class that will be looked up by it's variable name `dafaultTransaction`, and it's first defined in the `DS.Store` class at this line: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L119, and here it is instanciated: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L139